# select city with more than 2 employees sql

Tags: sql, database

I need select cities where are more than two employees with name "ged" and order them by department. This is my tables

```
empl            
 ide    fn  ln  debt
  43    ged trt 43
  73    ged res 43
 456    k   hjkhg   0
 532    kkhg    gfgf    23
  45    k   gdfg    79
 243    hj  vjv 78
 354    ged vt  78
 3421   ged vt  78

depart  
debt    city
  43    odesa
  23    kiev
  79    lviv
  78    lviv
```

I wrote such code

```
select  depart.CITY from depart inner join  empl on empl.DEBT=depart.DEBT
where empl.FN='ged'
group by empl.FN, depart.CITY
having count(empl.FN)>=2;
```

But it gives only one city - odesa

Comment: No it does not - please check [this Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1e8c/1). You get lviv and odesa.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your query - could some of the fn entries for 'ged' have whitespace around them? Does your database have a case sensitive collation (and some of your 'ged' values have caps in?)

Answer (score 5):

I dont find any problem with your query

Please see demo [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc300/1)

[image]

Comment: You might want to use `Text to DDL` feature of Sql Fiddle. Sometimes you need to manually erase some blanks but mostly it works quite nicely.

Answer (score -1):

```
select  depart.CITY from depart inner join  empl on empl.DEBT=depart.DEBT
where empl.FN='ged' order by empl.DEBT
```

Comment: You are ignoring this criterion: **I need select cities where are more than two employees with name "ged"**.